# Debugger for ArcGIS Java Script API 3.x?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, aptana

I am working on ArcGIS Java Script API version 3.2/3.3 and using IDE as [aptana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptana) & [notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++)(Currently testing all applications on Firefox and using Firebug while testing). Getting several errors while using JSAPI so is there any recommended Debugger available for ArcGIS JSAPI ?

I am also going through [resource link](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/mapconfig_debug.html).

Comment: I had worked extensively on the ESRI ArcGIS Javascript API for almost a year. Javascript debugging is always a very difficult task, so the problem is not with the API as such. The best debugger I could find for the purpose was Firebug. Occasionally Firebug also could not detect the errors and I had to load the code with print statements. Another issue that I faced was compatibility with different browsers. Be sure to continually check with all the browsers you intend to support. Doing it later can be a very difficult task.

Comment: Two more options are: Developer tools in Google Chrome, & WebStorm http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html#javascript_debugger_based_on_mozilla I personally prefer the Developer tool in Chrome to firebug, when it comes to JavaScript debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Dev tools is a solution for debugging.  It has a lot of features that can help speed up the process of development.  I use it everyday.